# Regex Expression to remove any html tag with a given class

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Can anyone help me with a regex expression that I can use to remove any html tag with a given class.

Example -

I have selected all tr in the dom and I have them as a string. But I will like to remove all tr's that has class, "world"..

```
<tr class="world"></tr>
<tr class="stack"></tr>
<tr class="hello world"></tr>
```

Note - I have them as a string because I would like to copy them to the clipboard. However, I would like this tag(with a given class) to remain the dom but not in the string I want to copy to the clipboard

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. Access the DOM and use the methods on the Element objects to remove the `tr` you need.

Comment: Html tags can have many attributes, in any order, which will break the regex.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you give example of this method? I currently need those elements in the DOM but would like to add the selected html (minus some tags with a given class) to the clipboard

Comment: Sure, I added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression isn't the right tool for this task.

To do what you require, select the `table` element from the DOM and clone it. You can then select the child `tr.world` elements from the cloned table, so you don't affect the instance currently in the DOM, before you get the resulting `innerHTML`. Here's a working example:

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table').cloneNode(true);
table.querySelectorAll('tr.world').forEach(el => el.remove());
let html = table.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML;

console.log(html);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="world"><td>World</td></tr>
  <tr class="stack"><td>Stack</td></tr>
  <tr class="hello world"><td>Hello world</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td>Foo</td></tr>
</table>
```